# Is there a name for the algorithm solutions for "booking rooms with the least room switches"?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I was discussing with a co-worker a problem we were having with a piece of software we deploy, and he mentioned how it was similar to the conceptual problem of booking rooms over a course of time and the algorithm should output the room bookings that requires the least switches (so for example, an optimal solution may be staying in one room for 3 days, and the rest in another room, only requiring two switches).

Is there a name for such a problem in algorithms?

Comment: I can think of a couple possible candidates, but I'd need a really precise statement of your problem to be sure.

Comment: Well the gist of it is that you have almost a chart of dates, telling when each room is available (say there's a check if it's available on that day). And say you have to book for a five day convention. What's the algorithm (or what's it called) to help you select what the schedule for those five days should be so that you have to swap rooms as little as possible. So preferably you'd stay in one room the whole time, but if you only have to swap once, that's okay, but worse, two even more worse, etc. Is that more clear?

Comment: Well, I can think of a problem in algorithms that is close. At the very least, it looks like you can turn this problem into an instance of one of those. Do you want me to describe it in an answer?

Comment: That would be great, yes.

Comment: Posted one idea, but if I find something else that's even closer, I'll update my answer.

Comment: (Especially since minimum set cover is NP-complete, and I'm not entirely convinced that your case isn't a special case that's easily solvable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I posted something regarding the [minimum set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). Although you can describe your problem as a minimum set cover problem, if we assume "room bookings" are over consecutive days, your problem can be more succinctly described with a different problem.

The **interval cover problem**<sup>1</sup> consists of one big interval (call it (a,b)), and a bunch of subintervals (call them (a<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>i</sub>)). Our goal is to cover the one big interval with as few subintervals as possible.

[Finding the minimal coverage of an interval with subintervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293168/finding-the-minimal-coverage-of-an-interval-with-subintervals) is a question posted about 5 years ago which asks for an efficient solution, and the accepted answer shows that the greedy solution is optimal. Within the context of room bookings, the "greedy solution" would be basically to start from the beginning of the period and always pick the booking with the latest end date.

The idea of course with this problem is that the each "subinterval" is a booking, so the fewer subintervals we need, the fewer bookings, and hence the fewer "switches" we need.

---

<sup>1 I'm not actually 100% sure that this is the correct name, but if you were to say "interval cover problem", the listener would probably think of the same thing.</sup>