# Design a Greedy algorithm for this preblem

Tags: algorithm, greedy

In the interval covering problem, we are given `n`  intervals

```
[s1,t1), [s2,t2), ···, [sn,tn)
```

such that

```
S i∈[n][si,ti) = [0,T).
```

The goal of the problem is to return a smallest-size set

```
S ⊆ [n]
```

such that

```
S i∈S[si,ti) = [0,T).
```

Design a greedy algorithm for this problem.

Comment: How about you do your own homework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the minimal coverage of an interval with subintervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293168/finding-the-minimal-coverage-of-an-interval-with-subintervals)

Comment: Possibly a special case of the vertex cover problem for interval graphs.

Comment: Please add more quantifiers to the formulation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A greedy algorithm could be devised as follows. As long as there is a point `p` in `[0,T)` which is not contained in one of the already selected intervals, select an interval `[s_i,t_i)` , which must exist, since the union of all `[s_i,t_i)` is `[0,T)` as stated in the requirements. As the set of intervals `[s_i,t_i)` is finite, this procedure must terminate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir but i need a complete solution of this problem

Comment: then sir I would recommend you log out here and start to work on the problem using the good hint Codor gave

Comment: do you really think anyone will do your homework for you? It's ok to ask hw-questions here but your are expected to show some kind of effort and usually we don't give complete answers as you will learn nothing from it - also: do you think it's a good idea to come in, post your demands and expect your solution *as soon as possible*?